# Вызвать дочернее окно pyqt5 с помощью QThread

Tags: python, pyqt, instagram, qthread

Есть программа для парсинга инсты. Сначала запускается панель со всем функционалом, далее для каждого аккаунта запускаются разные боты в разных потоках. Но в процессе необходимо подтверждение через код по смс. Так вот я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы когда произошла отправка смс на телефон, в программе поверх основного окна вываливалось дочернее, в котором надо вбить код из смс. Исходя из логики программы окно для ввода кода пытаюсь запустить в отдельном потоке, так как не хочу тормозить все остальные операции. Пробовал через  Thread, возникает ошибка и просит через QThread, полистав интернет, как так решения не нашел. Кто знает, как решить эту проблему?

```
class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(mywindow, self).__init__()
    self.ui = Ui_InstaBot()       
    self.ui.setupUi(self)  
    self.ui.LoginBtn.clicked.connect(self.login)
    self.ui.ExitBtn.clicked.connect(self.unLogin)
    self.ui.GetDialBtn.clicked.connect(self.getDial)
    self.ui.SendBtn.clicked.connect(self.send)
    self.ui.AccList.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.CheckCombo)
    self.AccArr = {}
    self.AccDialCount = {}
    self.AccMsgCount = {}
    self.MsgArr = {}
    self.WorkArr = {}
       

def checkLog(self, acc, obj):
    while(1==1):
        try:
            file = open(acc + ".txt", 'r', encoding='utf8')
            command = file.readlines()    
            
            if len(command[0]) >= 1 and command[0][0] == 's':
                QMessageBox.critical(self, "!!!", "Авторизация пользователя " + acc + " произведена успешно", QMessageBox.Ok) 
                
                file.close()
                break

            if len(command[0]) >= 1 and command[0][0] == 'u':
                QMessageBox.critical(self, "!!!", "Ошибка при авторизации " + acc, QMessageBox.Ok) 
                
                file.close()
                break

           if len(command[0]) >= 1 and command[0][0] == 'a':
                #Здесь надо вызвать дочернее окно
                file.close()
                break

        
        except:
            file.close()                
            continue

        
        

        file.close()                
        continue

def login(self):
    log = self.ui.Login.text()
    password = self.ui.Password.text()

    if log in self.AccArr:
        QMessageBox.critical(self, "Ошибка ", "Данный пользователь уже запущен", QMessageBox.Ok) 
        return

    if(log == '' or password == ''):   
        QMessageBox.critical(self, "Ошибка ", "Заполните поля логин и пароль", QMessageBox.Ok)           
        return

    #p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'telega.py', log, password])       
    
    self.WorkArr[log] = True

    self.AccArr[log] = password
    file = open(log + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')
    file.close()
    
    self.ui.CountDialog.setText("0")
    self.ui.CountMess.setText("0")
    self.ui.MsgText.setPlainText("")
    self.ui.AccList.addItem(log)

    th = Thread(target=self.checkLog, args=(log,self))

    th.start()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: добавил минимум